# Cleanest way to sum list of nested dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, python-3.6

Is there a cleaner/more pythonic way of summing the contents of a list of nested dicts? Here's what I'm doing, but I suspect that there may be a better way:

```
list_of_nested_dicts = [{'class1': {'TP': 1, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 2}, 'class2': {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}, 'class3': {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}, 'class4': {'TP': 1, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 2}},
                        {'class1': {'TP': 1, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 2}, 'class2': {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}, 'class3': {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}, 'class4': {'TP': 1, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 2}},
                        {'class1': {'TP': 1, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 2}, 'class2': {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}, 'class3': {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}, 'class4': {'TP': 1, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 2}},
                        {'class1': {'TP': 1, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 2}, 'class2': {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}, 'class3': {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}, 'class4': {'TP': 1, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 2}}]

total_counts = {k:{'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0} for k in list_of_nested_dicts[0].keys()}

for d in list_of_nested_dicts:
    for label,counts_dict in d.items():
        for k,v in counts_dict.items():
            total_counts[label][k] += v

print(total_counts)
```

(Assuming all keys are exactly the same, but values could be any integer)

Comment: honestly, this is pretty good. Could switch `total_counts` to be a defaultdict instead perhaps, but frankly i dont really see why this isn't fine.

Comment: or collections counter. and `list_of_nested_dicts[0].keys()` could be `list_of_nested_dicts[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing in your code that stands out as "unclean" is the fact that you are hard-coding the keys of the sub-dicts in the initialization of `total_counts`. You can avoid such hard-coding by using the `dict.setdefault` and `dict.get` methods as you iterate over the items of the sub-dicts instead:

```
total_counts = {}
for d in list_of_nested_dicts:
    for label, counts_dict in d.items():
        for k, v in counts_dict.items():
            total_counts[label][k] = total_counts.setdefault(label, {}).get(k, 0) + v
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a slightly tighter code using `collections` (similar result to @blhsing)

```py
import collections

counts = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
for d in list_of_nested_dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        counts[k].update(v)
```

This will give you a defaultdict of counters instead of only dicts, but they behave similarly.  You can also explicitly cast them to dicts at the end if you want.

```py
{'class1': {'FN': 8, 'FP': 0, 'TP': 4},
 'class2': {'FN': 0, 'FP': 0, 'TP': 0},
 'class3': {'FN': 0, 'FP': 0, 'TP': 0},
 'class4': {'FN': 8, 'FP': 0, 'TP': 4}}
```

vs

```py
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
            {'class1': Counter({'FN': 8, 'TP': 4, 'FP': 0}),
             'class2': Counter({'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}),
             'class3': Counter({'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'FN': 0}),
             'class4': Counter({'FN': 8, 'TP': 4, 'FP': 0})})
```